# rails: how to let user send a html email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailto

I want to let the user of my page send a html formated email to friends.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

yes it's possible but you can become a spam box if you don't check the content.

Comment: And how can I do this? can action mailer open up the email in the outlook of the user?

Comment: No if fetch text from a form and push it on view of actionmailer. Outlook is really not an application you can found on all client

Comment: But thats what I want to do: Wenn the user taps a certain link on my homepage, the users outlook should open up with html content inside the prepared email (like mail_to). The user has only to add the emailaddress of his friend to publish the email... is this possible?

Comment: so you can't to do it's html related not rails